# Show that $1-\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} - e^{-\lambda h} = o(h)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

We want to show that : $1-\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} - e^{-\lambda h} = o(h)$  with $\lambda>0$ a constant.

First, using the Taylor formula I have written this as $-o(1) - \lambda h - o(h)$ :

I use the fact that $e^{-\lambda h} = 1 + o(1)$  and $\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} = \lambda h + o(h)$

So $1-\lambda he^{-\lambda h} -e^{-\lambda h} = -o(1) -\lambda h - o(h) $ if I am right

So know I want to show that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{-o(1) - \lambda h - o(h)}{h} = 0$

But I don't know how to prove this, in fact I don't know how to start, $o(h)$ is easy to handle but $\lambda h$ and $o(1)$ put me in trouble. For $\lambda h$ I don't see how can I obtain a $o(h)$ since lambda is strictly positive and constant

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Thank you a lot

EDIT : From the comment of jjagmath so I thank him for that, hoping to have made this post clearer.

Comment: The statement is false.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. I cannot prove this so I cannot argue against your comment but can you explain me why it should be false please ?

Comment: What is true is $1-\lambda h-\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} - e^{-\lambda h} = o(h)$. This makes the statement in the title wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm The statement is true

Comment: "... using the Taylor formula I have written this as $−o(1)−\lambda h−o(h)$ ..." It's hard to tell where you made a mistake if you don't share your work. How did you arrive to that?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment jjagmath  ! I use the fact that $e^{-\lambda h} = 1 + o(1)$  and $\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} = \lambda h + o(h)$ . So $1-\lambda he^{-\lambda h} -e^{-\lambda h} = -o(1) -\lambda h - o(h) $ if I am right, I edited the post thanks to your comment ! I hope this is much clearer now

Comment: $e^x = 1 + o(1)$ is not a good enough approximation to get the result. You'll need $e^x = 1 + x+o(x)$

Comment: Well I get this which seems false since I cannot say that it is a small $o(h)$ . I have $1-\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} - e^{-\lambda h} = 1 - \lambda h + (\lambda h)^{2} - o((\lambda h)^2) - 1 + \lambda h - o(\lambda h) =  (\lambda h)^{2} - o( (\lambda h)^{2}) - o(\lambda h) $. In fact I wanted to manipulate the small o notation when seeing this exercise because it is something I have never studied before but it's more confusing than anything else and I don't know if it's appropriate here given the response to this post.

Comment: @coboy Are you interested in an answer using the small $o$ notation?

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you for your answer really. In all honesty I would like to because I feel that my understanding of this small $o$ notation is poor when I see what I write with

Comment: @coboy I added a new answer using the $o$ notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer using the $o$ notation:

Since $e^x = 1+x+o(x)$ when $x \to 0$ we have

\begin{align}
1-\lambda\ h\ e^{-\lambda\ h} - e^{-\lambda\ h} & = 1-\lambda\ h\ (1-\lambda\ h + o(h))-(1-\lambda\ h + o(h))\\
&=1-\lambda\ h+\lambda^2h^2+o(h^2)-1+\lambda\ h + o(h)\\
&=\lambda^2h^2+o(h^2) + o(h)\\
&=o(h)+o(h)+o(h) = o(h)
\end{align}

when $h \to 0$.

Note that we used some properties of the $o$ notation as $o(\lambda\ h) = o(h)$, $o(h^2) = o(h)$ and $o(h) + o(h) = o(h)$.

Comment: Oooh okay for $(\lambda h)^{2}$ you use the fact that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\lambda h)^{2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\lambda^{2} h = 0$ ? With your notation and especially the neighborhood on which you work that is specified it is much clearer.  Thank you a lot for your time on this post, you did more than help someone today !

Answer (score 2):

What you need to prove is that $$\lim_{h\to\color{red}0}\frac{1-\lambda h e^{-\lambda h} - e^{-\lambda h}}{h} =0$$ which follows from L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: This makes sense indeed, and you specify clearly at what neighborhood you are working something I was not able to do because it was not mention, so how did you think to take  $$h at a neighborhood of $0$ ? I mean this is a real question because even my exercise does not precise that (exercise about probability in fact) and it was confusing